# $scope.watchCollection in angular js is triggered only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an object array which has two nested objects in it. The structure is as below. I am having watch functions to watch any update or push or delete of the extraCurricular nested objects. But those functions are triggered only once. I dont have any stop function for these watch functions.So I am not stopping them. Please let me know where I am wrong

$scope.class.student.extraCurriculars = {
    games: [{
        name: 'Volley Ball',
        teamCount: 10
    }, {
        name: 'Chess',
        teamCount: 2
    }],
    arts: [{
            dance: {
                type: 'Bharatham',
                teamCount: '1'
            },
            music: {
                type: 'Carnatic',
                teamCount: '1'
            }]
    }
}

Each student can be in more than one games, and more than one arts.

```
**studentExtraCurriculum.html**

<div class="ui raised blue segment">
    <div class="ui accordion" ng-repeat="game in class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars.games">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="ui green label">{{$index+1}}</div>
            <select ng-model="game.name" ng-options="game as game.name for game in gamesList">
                <option value="">{{gamesList.game.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" size="3" placeholder="Team count" ng-model="game.teamCount "></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui small button" ng-click="pushGames()">Add a Game</div>
<div class="ui raised blue segment">
    <div class="ui accordion" ng-repeat="art in class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars.arts">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="ui green label">{{$index+1}}</div>
            <select ng-model="art.name" ng-options="art as art.name for game in artList">
                <option value="">{{artList.art.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" size="3" placeholder="Team count" ng-model="art.teamCount "></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui small button" ng-click="pushArts()">Add a Art</div>
```

**MyController.js**

```
 var extraCurriculumController = function($scope, $log, StudentService, $stateParams, ClassService, Modal, $compile, $window) {
function {
...
}
function {
...,
}
function _init(){
...
//Inside Init I have added watch functions
$scope.$watchCollection(
            "class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("Deep change bat");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        );
        $scope.$watchCollection(
            "class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("Deep change bowl");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        );

        //watch for shallow change in array
        $scope.$watch("class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("Shallow change bat");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        );
        $scope.$watch("class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("Shallow change bowl");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        );

        //deep change tree lookup
        $scope.$watch("class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("tree change bat");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            },
            true
        );
        $scope.$watch("class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars",
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("tree change bowl");
                console.log("Old value");
                console.log(oldValue);
                console.log("New Value");
                console.log(newValue);
            },
            true
        );
//End of watch function
}

}
```

Comment: In your view you're using `ng-repeat="game in class.student.extraCurriculars.games"`, why are you watching `"class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars"` where does [curSection - 1] come from? (Also, you're watching the extraCurriculars object, not the collections)

Comment: Sorry I missed to add that part in the code. Added now.

Comment: The error still remains

Comment: I had problems with this as well.. Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621 Seems like a buggy feature.

Comment: No. My problem is , the watchcollection is not called for ANY change in the collection. newValue=oldValue is secondary. Infact, I dont have any requirement for comparing them. If it is triggered thats helpful for me. Thats it.

Comment: But are you watching `class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars.games`? Your code says `$watchCollection('class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars'...` and that's watching the object containing the arrays, not the arrays.

Comment: Now I am using class.student[curSection - 1].extraCurriculars.games. But still the issue remains.